# how to give access to os.remove() in python?

Tags: python

I want to delete a folder with

```
os.remove(example)
```

but I get Access denied error, what is the easiest way to give access?

Comment: `"Remove (delete) the file path. If path is a directory, OSError is raised. Use rmdir() to remove directories."` https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove

Comment: its for empty directories only

Answer (score 1):

Change the file permission to 0777.
For those who are confused as to why 0777 is not working.
For Python 3, try using 0o777 instead of 0777.

```
os.chmod(PATH, 0o777)
os.remove(PATH)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is a file in read only mode, change the file permission to 0777 with os.chmod() function and then try to remove it with os.remove().

```
os.chmod(filePath, 0777)
os.remove(filePath)
```

If it is a directory, do the same but with os.removedir() instead of os.remove().

```
os.chmod(dirPath, 0777)
os.removedir(dirPath)
```

Comment: why chmod is required? If the calling user doesn't have to delete file then it will fail to change mode (chmod) too..

Comment: @Ana Rednic i get invalid token error for 0777,what am i doing wrong?777 works but still get access denied!